# Remove characters from a variable

Tags: php

I have the following in a variable, `|MyString|`

I want to strip the leading `|` and the ending `|` returning `MyString`

What is the quickest and non intensive way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way is probably

```
$result = trim($input, '|');
```

http://docs.php.net/trim

e.g.

```
<?php
$in = '|MyString|';
$result = trim($in, '|');

echo $result;
```

prints `MyString`

Comment: `+1 for quick response` - yes, a shameless quick-rep-grab question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the str_replace function in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
this should remove all '|' characters:

`str_replace('|','',$myString)`

You may be able to use a regular expression to only remove the first and last '|' or alternatively using the String trim() function may also work:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

So, something like this:

```
$trimmedMyString = trim($myString, "|");
```

Worth trying anyway.

Comment: Reference Sudhir's answer. Using `str_replace` is an incorrect answer.

Comment: Yes, probably not relevant in this case, but using regex, or trim probably is.